# Unable to determine end of Postgres output in expanded mode

Tags: python, postgresql, pexpect

I am new to Python and trying to get output from pg table using pexpect library in python.

Case 1:
In normal view(\x off) in am able to get entire output as the total number of rows comes down after the records are displayed. So i am using that count as regular expression("(\d) row)" to calculate the end - remote_host.expect('((\d) row', timeout=20)`.

Ex :

[image: Non-expanded view]

Case 2:
But i need the output in expanded format("\x on"). Hence added "\x on" but this does not gives me a regular expression to calculate or find the ending of the output.

Ex :
[image: expanded view]

So in case 2 i do not have anything to find out where it ends. I am trying to fetch the table from cli to my python script using pexpect

I am using python 2.x

Comment: Please properly format your code

Comment: Hi @kevin He, What do you mean by formatting my code properly ? Can you elaborate and guide me

Comment: see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)